# jQuery popup with image (box with black transparent overlay) on HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a webpage, that will have a jQuery popup with a image that will appear automatically when a  website loads. I want the popup to create a black transparent overlay,(link:) [like this](http://i66.tinypic.com/2hoz9fb.jpg). It was easier to create that popup. But I fail to do this with the image. I want the popup to appear 30% from the left border of the page. The image and the black overlay shall disaper on hover and reappear when the user moves the mouse. How am I to do?

Here is the Html code:

```
 <head>
    script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <a class="cha" data-popup-open="popup-imonelle" href="#"></a>
    <div class="cha-popup" data-popup="popup-imonelle">
       <div class="popup-pic">
          <img src="Images/imonelle.jpg"/>
          <a class="popup-hover" data-popup-close="popup-imonelle" href="#">x</a>
       </div>
    </div>
 </body>
 <footer>
    <script src="js/Sciptquery.js"></script>
 </footer>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    //----- OPEN when page loads
    $(function(e)  {
        var targeted_popup_class = $('[cha-popup-close]').attr('cha-popup-close');
        $('[cha-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
    });

    //----- CLOSE on hover
    $('[cha-popup-close]').on('hover', function(e)  {
        var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('cha-popup-close');
        $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);

        e.preventDefault();
    });
 });
 });
```

And last, the CSS code:

```
        .cha-popup {
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            display:none;
            position:fixed;
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
            background:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
                       }

        /* Inner */
        .popup-pic {
            max-width:845px;
            width:90%;
            padding:0px;
            position:absolute;
            top:50%;
            left:30%;
            -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
            box-shadow:0px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,1);
            border-radius:3px;
            background:#fff;
        }

        /* Close on hover function */
        .popup-hover {
            transition:ease 0.25s all;
            -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%);
            transform:translate(50%, -50%);
        }
        }
    }
```

I have modified the code I used for the popup on the image that is attached to the post. But something is clearly wrong.

Comment: Is this inspired by some design that you can refer us ? may be an existing site? It seems that you want the image to popup/highlighted with black/transparent overlay when the mouse is hovered over it. But just want to confirm if that is the case...

Comment: Yeah, I mean .cha-popup (you can find it in the .css). The popup is inspired by this tutorial: [link]http://inspirationalpixels.com/tutorials/custom-popup-modal. I want the popup and the transparent overlay (outside the box) to appear when the page loads, and to disappear while the mouse is hovering over it.

Comment: This should have been a separate question once you changed it, instead of getting answers to your original question, then changing it. Please see a few Meta discussions regarding proper etiquette regarding changing your question to something else after answers are present: [1](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252113/how-to-deal-with-constant-changing-questions), [2](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309237/dealing-with-questions-that-are-edited-after-my-answer-has-been-accepted), [3](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295089/op-changes-a-question-after-it-has-been-answered).

Comment: I agree with @Santi. I had edited the question to make some general improvements, and had not noticed that the substantial changes were made after the below answers. I have now rolled it back. Please ask a new question, or ping me at `@halfer` for more guidance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from a few simple syntax issues, the main issue here is with your selectors. Let's take a look at some of them...

```
    //[cha-popup-close]
    var targeted_popup_class = $('[cha-popup-close]').attr('cha-popup-close');

    //[cha-popup]
    $('[cha-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);

    //[data-popup]
    $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
```

A selector within square brackets like `[cha-popup-close]` is looking for *an attribute of `cha-popup-close`*.

If you look at your HTML, you do not have any elements that have an attribute named `cha-popup` or `cha-popup-close`, and so essentially none of your selectors are actually selecting anything.

The `[data-popup]` selector is the only one that will actually find anything, because there *are* elements with a `data-popup` attribute.

---

Using the proper selectors, I believe what you're after is something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Get popup to open and fade it in
    var targeted_popup_class = $('[data-popup-open]').data('popup-open');
    $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);

    //CLOSE on hover
    $('[data-popup-close]').on('mouseover', function(e) {

        //Get popup to close and hide it
        var targeted_popup_class = $(this).data("popup-close");
        $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);

    });

});
```

[**Here's your example, fixed.**](https://jsfiddle.net/zxLtpb1e/)

In addition to fixing up your selectors, I've tidied up your code a bit, fixed the extra curly brackets you had laying around, and most notably changed your `.on("hover")` (which doesn't work) to `.on("mouseover")`